# How to config credentials in Source Code Management section in Github Plugin for Jenkins?

Tags: github, jenkins

[Here](https://github.com/nicolasxu/hello-nick-jenkins) is the test project I want Jenkins to build when there is new commit to this Github repo.

Here is the section on Jenkins for enter credentials for Github:

[image]
I know:

- how to add SSH on Github
- how account name and password works

But when I click this "Add", this huge window pops out:[image]

I am freaked out since the form fields doens't match

- account name & password,
- SSH

I don't know how to fill the form to allow Jenkin to pull code from Github and start the build.

Please tell me how to fill the credential form to allow Jenkins to pull code from Github.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use ssh, you should:

- use an ssh url:

  ```
  ssh://git@github.com/<username>/<reponame>
  ```
- Make sure to have the [JENKINS SSH Credentials Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/SSH+Credentials+Plugin) installed.

Then the popup should prompt you to define an ssh credential (registering a private key, since you have [added the public key to your GitHub account profile](https://help.github.com/articles/adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-github-account/))